# HTML tags are visible under the tag warning

Tags: bug, tags

While adding [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) on a question, a warning message appeared under. We can see the HTML tags. I am sure they were not intended to be there and need to be replaced by bullets.

[image]